# GWT - Range error: Maximum call stack size exceeded at spliceArray

Tags: javascript, gwt, arraylist

When I try to add an object that has a very large number of elements to another arrayList using the addAll method, I get the following exception :

```
Range error: Maximum call stack size exceeded at spliceArray
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in GWT-2.5.1.

Instead of using addAll method, use the add method to insert objects individually in the target arrayList.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8243