# gwt obfuscated maximum call stack size exceeded Object._toString

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am using GWT and I get error maximum call stack size exceeded when only compiling obfuscated with GWT. If I compile pretty with GWT, I dont have this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GWT - Range error: Maximum call stack size exceeded at spliceArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980754/gwt-range-error-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-at-splicearray)

Answer (score 0):

not sure your problem, however, gwt version before 2.6 has a bug which will cause the call stack exceeded in some browsers if you have a very long string value, please try 2.6.1